# murmurhash-native NODE_MODULE_VERSION incompatibility when installing @mapbox/carmen in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, mapbox

I'm trying to install [@mapbox/carmen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/carmen) inside docker to use it in node.js app. Install goes without any errors on both yarn and npm, but I get the same error on app statup:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The module '/app/node_modules/murmurhash-native/lib/Release/murmurhash.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/murmurhash-native/index.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

I use node:10 image so I assusme npm would use corresponding pre-built package when installing murmurhash-native (which is a dependency of carmen), but looks like it does not.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mapbox_service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/carmen": "32.0.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

USER root
WORKDIR /app

COPY "./package.json" ./

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl
RUN apt-get update

# Get Rust
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y
ENV PATH=/usr/local/cargo/bin:$PATH

RUN npm install

COPY src .
EXPOSE 8080

RUN node --version
CMD [ "node", "src" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  nodejs:
    image: "node:10"
    container_name: nodejs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    expose:
      - "3080"
    ports:
      - "3080:3080"
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      - PORT=3080
    command: "node src"

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  node_modules:
```

**What can I do to force npm to use proper murmurhash-native package?**
Also, node version on host machine is v12.16.1, but I doubt npm uses it to justify package build usage.

Comment: The `volumes:` tell Docker that you're storing critical user data in the `node_modules` directory, and it must not update that directory lest that user data get corrupted.  Delete the `volumes:` block.  (...and please don't paste screen shots of terminal windows into SO questions; include the actual text of the error.)

Comment: Thank you, it worked once I removed all `volumes:` blocks. Added actual text of error as well. Please write actual answer so I can accept it.